# :before and :after CSS properties not working in MPDF

Tags: mpdf

`:before` and `:after` CSS properties ignoring in mpdf library. Any alternatives to counter increment and content CSS?

```html
    <style>
                body {
                    counter-reset:counter; 
                }
                .list {
                   display: table;  
                   color:red;                           
                }
                .list:before {                
                    font-size: 16pt;
                    display: table-cell;
                     counter-increment: counter; 
                    content: counter(counter) ". ";
                    padding-right: 5px;
                }
             </style>
            <h5>Hello World</h5>
            <p class="list">first.</p>
            <p class="list">second.</p>
```

This is the sample html.